# Why is the 2nd term in this If-AndAlso statement evaluated early?

Tags: vb.net

**Edit for clarity:** This is a pretty odd behaviour from the compiler, I'm asking for why it behaves this way in general, rather than how to work around it (there are several simple solutions already).

Recently, I came across a piece of code which throws contains a subtle mistake, and ends up throwing an exception.  A shortened, contrived example:

```
Dim list As List(Of Integer) = Nothing
If list?.Any() AndAlso list.First() = 123 Then
    MessageBox.Show("OK then!")
End If
```

In the real example, `list` was only occasionally `Nothing`, I'm just shortening the code for clarity.  The intention with the first term in the `If` statement was to both check that list is not `Nothing`, and to also test for the existence of at least one element.  Since in this case, `list` is `Nothing`, the `list?.Any()` actually / typically evaluates to `Nothing`.  Somewhat counter-intuitively, the 2nd term, namely `list.First() = 123` is **also** evaluated by the runtime, causing an obvious exception.  This is somewhat counter-intuitive, since at first guess most people would imagine that `Nothing` is seem as `False`, and since we're using an `AndAlso` here, the short-circuit operator would prevent the 2nd half of the `If` statement from executing.

**Additional investigation / "What have you tried:"**

Quick check to confirm that a shortened `If list?.Any() Then` seems to treat `list?.Any()` as a `False`:

```
Dim list As List(Of Integer) = Nothing

If list?.Any() Then
    MessageBox.Show("OK then!")   'This line doesn't get hit / run
End If
```

Also, we can work around the issue by in several ways: `If list IsNot Nothing AndAlso list.Any() AndAlso list.First() = 123 Then` would work just fine, as would `If If(list?.Any(), False) AndAlso list.First() = 123 Then`.

Since VB.Net is not my usual language, I thought I'd have a look at this in C#:

```
List<int> list = null;
if (list?.Any() && list.First() == 123)
{
    MessageBox.Show("OK then!");
}
```

However, this gives a compilation error:

```
error CS0019: Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool?' and 'bool'
```

Apart from the obvious fact that the stricter compiler check would prevent this mistake from being made in the C# scenario, this leads me to believe that type coercion is happening in the VB.Net scenario.  One guess might be that the compiler is trying to cast the Boolean result of the 2nd term to a nullable Boolean, however this doesn't make a whole lot of sense to me.  Specifically, why would it evaluate it prior to / same time as the left side, and abandoning the entire process early, like it should? Looking back at the VB.Net examples that do work correctly, all involve explicit checks which have a simple Boolean result, rather than a nullable Boolean.

My hope is that someone can give some good insight into this behaviour!

Comment: You could handle it this way: `If list?.FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x = 123) Then ...`

Comment: Unfortunately this is [by design](https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/69), same reason the C# compiler doesn't like it.  But without the diagnostic, it could certainly use a warning.  You need the long version, If list IsNot Nothing AndAlso list.Any() AndAlso .. Then

Comment: @HansPassant you're right, it indeed does seem to be by design.  The truth table in the linked official docs makes it pretty clear (since the compiler wants to differentiate between the Nothing vs False result, it needs to evaluate the 2nd operand).  Though, I suppose since neither of those two lead to a truthy result, the compiler could have just optimised the 2nd evaluation out completely.

Comment: I think this is a bug in the compiler, it should never get to AndAlso, but as a pragmatic answer you should be using list?.First = 123 as that solves the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an omission(bug) in the VB compiler's syntax evaluation.  The documentation for the [?. and ?() null-conditional operators (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) states:

> Tests the value of the left-hand operand for null (Nothing) before
>   performing a member access (?.) or index (?()) operation; returns
>   Nothing if the left-hand operand evaluates to Nothing. Note that, in
>   the expressions that would ordinarily return value types, the
>   null-conditional operator returns a Nullable.

The expression `list?.Any()` ([Enumerable.Any Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.7.2)) would ordinarily return a `Boolean` (a ValueType), so we should expect `list?.Any()` to yield a Nullable(Of Boolean).

We should see a compiler error as a Nullable(Of Boolean) can not participate in an [AndAlso Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/andalso-operator) expression.

Interestingly, if we treat `list?.Any()` as a Nullable(Of Boolean), it is seen as documented.

```
If (list?.Any()).HasValue() AndAlso list.First = 123 Then
 ' something
End If
```

---

Edit:  The above does not really address your *why?*.

If you de-compile the generated IL, you get something like this:

```
 Dim source As List(Of Integer) = Nothing
 Dim nullable As Boolean?
 Dim nullable2 As Boolean? = nullable = If((Not source Is Nothing), New Boolean?(Enumerable.Any(Of Integer)(source)), Nothing)
 nullable = If((nullable2.HasValue AndAlso Not nullable.GetValueOrDefault), False, If((Enumerable.First(Of Integer)(source) Is &H7B), nullable, False))
 If nullable.GetValueOrDefault Then
    MessageBox.Show("OK then!")
 End If
```

This obviously will will not compile, but if we clean it up a bit, the source of the issue becomes apparent.

```
Dim list As List(Of Integer) = Nothing
Dim nullable As Boolean?
Dim nullable2 As Boolean? = If(list IsNot Nothing, 
        New Boolean?(Enumerable.Any(Of Integer)(list)),
        Nothing)

' nullable2 is nothing, so the 3rd line below is executed and throws the NRE

nullable = If((nullable2.HasValue AndAlso Not nullable.GetValueOrDefault),
        False,
        If((Enumerable.First(Of Integer)(list) = 123), nullable, False))

If nullable.GetValueOrDefault Then
    MessageBox.Show("OK then!")
End If
```

---

Edit2:

The OP has found the following statement from the documentation for [Nullable Value Types (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/nullable-value-types)

> AndAlso and OrElse, which use short-circuit evaluation, must evaluate
>   their second operands when the first evaluates to Nothing.

This statement makes sense if `Option Strict Off` is in force and using the [OrElse Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/orelse-operator) as `Nothing` can implicitly be converted to `False`.  For the `OrElse` operator, the second expression is not evaluated only if the first expression is `True`. In the case of the `AndAlso` operator, the second operator is not evaluated if the first expression is `True`.

Also, consider the following code snippet with `Option Strict On`.

```
Dim list As List(Of Integer) = Nothing
Dim booleanNullable As Nullable(Of Boolean) = list?.Any()
Dim b As Boolean = (booleanNullable AndAlso list.First() = 123)
If b Then
    ' do something
End If
```

This re-arrangement of the original logic does yield a compiler error.
[image: compiler error]

With `Option Strict Off`, no compiler error is generated, yet the same run-time error occurs.

**My Conclusion:**  As originally stated, this is a bug.  When an `AndAlso` operator is included in a `If-Then` block the compiler treats the result of the null conditional operator using `Option Strict Off` type conversion relaxation regardless of the actual state of `Option Strict`.

Comment: I think this is along the right tracks, I'll try to look into it in more detail.  Interestingly, I found some official documentation mentioning the behaviour: [Nullable Value Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/nullable-value-types), quote: "Note: AndAlso and OrElse, which use short-circuit evaluation, must evaluate their second operands when the first evaluates to Nothing.", but it does not offer rationale, just a warning of sorts.

Comment: Actually, looking at the Nullable Value Types link, the behaviour becomes obvious; essentially, Nothing is treated in a funny way, apparently by definition.  The truth table provided says that Nothing And True equals Nothing, while Nothing And False equals **False**, meaning that the compiler **has to** evaluate the 2nd operand to differentiate between the two possible outcomes.  Hence with nullable booleans, Nothing != false (!!).  If you agree with this, and want to update the answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: @DanielB The reason for this behavior is, I believe, somewhat historical, and aiming to mimic the behavior of the `Null` value in classic VB.  You could use `GetValueOrDefault` on the nullable Boolean value you get back from your null conditional.  Also of note, I believe you can answer your own question, since the result of your research is the correct answer.

Comment: @DanielB, I looked at your link and have added a second edit to my answer to address this.  In short, I view that found note as misleading and partially in error (not the first time the documentation has issues).  This should issue should be reported to the [rosyln team](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues).

Comment: @TnTinMn I still don't think there is any bug involved here.  I think it's clearly by-design behavior given the history of VB and `Null` values.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that there are some technical details to how `AndAlso` and `OrElse` work that become important in a case like this: it is not strictly true that they involve implicit conversions to `Boolean`.  Rather, they will apply `Operator True` (in the case of `OrElse`) and `Operator False` in preference, and it may be the case that there are system-defined overrides of these for `Boolean?`.  If you really want your mind blown, read a very recent article by Eric Lippert on definite assignment in C# which involves pathological versions of these operators.

Answer (score 0):

Due in part to its heritage of strong support for database access, classic VB supported Null values as a first-class part of the type system.  Null is included in the truth tables for all of the built-in logical operators (for example, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/imp-operator ).

For this reason, it is not surprising that (as you later noted) VB would choose to use similar semantics to a classic Null for a `Boolean?` which does not have a value.

As a practical matter, the best way to address this is probably the following:

```
If (list?.Any()).GetValueOrDefault() AndAlso list.First() = 123 Then
```

In the alternative, you could use `FirstOrDefault` to avoid needing the check `Any` first, although this does rely on the value you seek not being the default (or using a "magic" replacement value, remember that you can override the default in `GetValueOrDefault`), e.g.

```
If list?.FirstOrDefault().GetValueOrDefault() = 123 Then
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try

```
if (list?.Any() IsNot Nothing AndAlso list.First() == 123)
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but there are two problems: 1) this still fails (since a False result from Any() will not be Nothing, and hence the 2nd part of the if will still run and throw an exception if the list is non-Nothing, but emty), but more importantly, the question is about why this happens in the first place, i.e. rationale of the compiler, not work-arounds.